# Android 1.6: onActivityResult is not called

Tags: android

I have a problem with the method "onActivityResult".
I create a new Activity from my main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The new Activity is ended like this:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("vid", hmvenues.get(venues[currentPosition]));
resultIntent.putExtra("name", venues[currentPosition]);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

But the Method onActivityResult seem to be not called

```
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
   Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"onActivityResult");
   ...
}
```

Does anyone have an idea, what I did wrong?
Thanks!! Seb

Comment: have you defined a android:launchMode in your activity???

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I found the error:
I had another Activity open, which was on the Activity stack between those Activities and caused the problem.